# Finding a palindrome from anagrams

Tags: python

I am attempting to find palindromes from a generated list of anagrams. The twist here is that my initial input is a list of palindromes. I am essentially trying to automate a hunt for a palindrome that is an anagram of a palindrome (not homework, just an English nerd).

The original palindromes for input will come from 'pals.txt' where the palindromes are line-separated and have had spaces and non-numerical characters removed. I am using the British-English dictionary file 'dictionary.txt' to generate the anagrams.

I would appreciate any input as I am still very much a beginning programmer. Thank you!

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    return s.lower() == s[::-1].lower()

def anagramchk(word,chkword):
    for letter in word:
        if letter in chkword:
            chkword = chkword.replace(letter, '', 1)
        else:
            return 0
    return 1

f0 = open('pals.txt', 'r')
f1 = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')
for line in f0:
    wordin = line
    for line in f1:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) >= 4:
            if anagramchk(line, wordin):
                if isPalindrome(line):
                    print line
f0.close()
f1.close()
```

Comment: where is `wordin` defined? (or is that an input parameter of a hypothetical function?)

Comment: Instead of your `anagramchk`, you could simply use `sorted(word.lower()) == sorted(chkword.lower())` -- the sorting puts all anagrams in a canonical order -- or you could use the `collections.Counter` class -- `Counter(word.lower()) == Counter(chkword.lower())` -- which compares the counts instead.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I was missing a line sorry about that. This brings up another issue for me, can I nest multiple "line" calls like that?

Comment: @DSM since I imagine efficiency will be important (lots of words to go through) would the use of counter or sorted be quicker?

Comment: @ajnachakra: Your solution is O(n^2). Mine is O(n), and works for your case quite easily. Check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import collections

def isPalindrome(s):
    return s.lower() == s[::-1].lower()

def anagramchk(word,chkword):
    return sorted(word.lower()) == sorted(chkword.lower())

def allAnagrams(dictfilepath):
    answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
    with open(dictfilepath) as dictfile:
        for line in dictfile:
            word = line.strip().lower()
            answer[''.join(sorted(word))].append(word)
    return answer

def fetchAllAnagrams(wordin, anagrams):
    return anagrams[''.join(sorted(wordin.lower()))]

def main(dictfilepath, palsfilepath):
    anagrams = allAnagrams(dictfilepath)
    with open(palsfilepath) as palfile:
        for line in palfile:
            word = line.strip().lower()
            if isPalindrome(word):
                for anagram in anagrams[''.join(sorted(word))]:
                    if isPalindrome(anagram):
                        print "%s is an anagram of %s" %(anagram, word)
```

Suppose your filepaths are `'path/to/dictfile'` and `'path/to/palsfile'`, then you could call `main` as follows:

```
main('path/to/dictfile', 'path/to/palsfile')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @irrelephant: you're right. Thanks for the bugreport. Resolved

Comment: Thank you! Will this work if I add something like the following to the beginning: dictfilepath = 'dictionary.txt'
palsfilepath = 'pals.txt' (given that they are in the same dir)

Comment: You can do that, or call `main` with those arguments directly. It will work in either case

Comment: I am truly striving to learn here, but I am getting syntax errors wherever I attempt to implement the file locations (be it at the beginning or in the main function). Could you show me how you would insert the file locations (giving they are in the same folder as the program) as it is not working for me at all? Thank you, and I apologize for the incompetence.

Comment: @ajnachakra: added something that I hope will help. Take a look at it and if you still have trouble, leave a comment

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still getting errors. It may be because I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.5 with Python 2.7.1 because I get the following errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "palCheckInAnaGen.py", line 27, in <module>
    main('dictionary.txt', 'pal.txt')
  File "palCheckInAnaGen.py", line 19, in main
    anagrams = allAnagrams(dictfilepath)
  File "palCheckInAnaGen.py", line 8, in allAnagrams
    answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
NameError: global name 'collections' is not defined

Comment: You should really look through [the python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), if that one threw you off. I've fixed the post, anyways

Comment: I will look through those again, I certainly missed something, thank you!

Comment: Simple syntax error on my part. Works like a charm, thank you!